# Configure Azure App Service to allow downloading *.config files

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I am trying to serve a clickonce app from an azure appservice. One of the files it must download is a .config file. These are treated as special files by azure as far as i can tell, and it will not let them be accessed via html (it just 404s). I tried setting a web.config and allowing the mimetype on the off chance this made a difference, but no joy.

Any suggestions?